# use my user id to access azure APIs (non interactive)

Tags: azure-authentication

i know how to use Azure API in following way.

1. go to app registration and create new app
2. get "client id", "Directory (tenant) ID" and secret.
3. go to "API permission" section and add what API you want to access.
   OR
   use app-id as SP and add it to role like "billing reader" and it will work too.
4. then use /oauth2/token pass client_id and client_secret and get bearer token.
5. then use any API by passing "Bearer {{access_token}}" in header and everything works.

**But**

1. what if i want to use API like billing or Cost Management or "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" but by my ID? what will be the flow? how to get bearer token from /oauth2/token by using my ID (my AD email)?

AND

2. is it possible to use my privilege but without me passing my password?  can i authorize some app_id to emulate as me for like an hr ?

Answer (score 1):

To generate bearer token in non-interactive way, **Client credentials flow** is mostly recommended.

If you want to get bearer token using your ID, you can make use of **`OAuth 2.0 ROPC grant flow`**.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I generated access token via **Postman** by providing parameters like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
scope : https://management.azure.com/.default
username : sri@xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password : xxxxxxx
client_secret : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using the above token, I'm able to call API to get ***list of storage accounts (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts)*** successfully like below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2021-09-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please **note** that, **`password`** parameter is mandatory for this flow.

**Reference:**

[Resource owner password credentials grant | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)