# Permissions required to delete specific Azure resource RestAPI

Tags: azure-rbac

I'm trying to delete one Azure Resource using RestAPI by following this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/delete-by-id

I have the access token with scope as https:/management.azure.com/.default where I granted user_impersonation too.

The problem is when I used the token to delete the resource for this query:

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/{resourceId}?api-version=2021-04-01
```

I'm getting error like:

> Status Code(403): 'Forbidden', Response from server:
> '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client ' ' with
> object id ' ' does not have authorization to perform action over scope
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials."}}'

I'm the owner of the subscription and I have Global Administrator role that has high privilege. What more roles are needed to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the below results:***

In my Azure Portal, I have one storage account in **`Sri`** resource group as below:

[image]

By passing ***access token*** generated with same scope as you, I ran below query and got same error:

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/{resourceId}?api-version=2021-04-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

The error usually occurs if your service principal **doesn't have** required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the action.

To resolve the error, you need to assign **role** to your service principal based on the **`resource_type`** you are deleting.

In my case, I assigned **"Storage Account Contributor"** role to the service principal at **`resource_group level`** as I'm deleting storage account like below:

[image]

After assigning that role, I generated the **access token** again like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

When I ran the same query with above access token, I got response **`200 OK`** as below:

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/{resourceId}?api-version=2021-04-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm this, you can visit **`Sri`** resource group in **Azure Portal** and you cannot find storage account as it is deleted.

[image]

So, assign the **`role`** accordingly to the **service principal** based on your requirement.

Alternatively, you can directly assign the **`Contributor`** role to the service principal that can delete **any** resource.

If you want to access the Azure resource using your ***user account roles***, you can generate access token via **`ROPC flow`**.

**Reference:**

[Resource owner password credentials grant  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)

Comment: I want to access Azure resource with my account only so I tried with ROPC flow as you mentioned but it's a bit confusing. Can you help me with any working example? Thanks!

Comment: You can refer **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469640/use-my-user-id-to-access-azure-apis-non-interactive/73557774#73557774)** regarding ***ROPC flow*** that I answered previously.

Comment: In the end, I followed your answer as I feel exposing password of my account in ROPC flow is not best security practice. Granting role to the service principal worked!